# multiple controllers with routing in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This is how i defined controller files

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/services/route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/controllers/mainController.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/controllers/configController.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/controllers/examController.js"></script>
```

And this is how my route.js looks like

```
$routeProvider.when('/config', {
    templateUrl: 'views/config.html',
    controller: 'configController'
});

$routeProvider.when('/exam', {
    templateUrl: 'views/exam.html',
    controller: 'examController'
});
```

What i'm doing is i have defined a

`$scope.a = true` in `configController.js`

And i'm accessing it in `examController.js`

But now `$scope.a` is getting `undefined` .

How i extend $scope.a from configController to examController ?

Answer (score 0):

You can share value from one controller to another with using of "shared service"

**FirstController:**

```
 function FirstCtrl($scope, mySharedService) {
      $scope.passData(params){
         mySharedService.setValues(params);
      }
 }
```

**SharedService:**

```
    angular.module("yourAppName", []).factory("mySharedService", function($rootScope){

        var mySharedService = {};

        mySharedService.values = {};

        mySharedService.setValues = function(params){
            mySharedService.values = params;
            $rootScope.$broadcast('dataPassed');
        }

        return mySharedService; 
   });
```

**SecondController:**

```
function SecondController($scope, mySharedService) {
    $scope.$on('dataPassed', function () {
        $scope.newItems = mySharedService.values;
    });
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to use $rootScope instead of $scope. use like this:

```
$rootScope.a = true in configController.js

//Now get it in examController

$rootScope.a in examController.js
```

Don't forget to include $rootScope as dependency.